# 1960s(?) Sci-fi movie about a caped man called the 'Prince of the Universe'

Tags: story-identification, movie

OK about 40+ years ago I remember seeing a movie on TV about a man who either referred to himself or was called the "Prince of the Universe" (no relation to highlander).

I don't have many details to give other than (if memory serves) he was dressed all in white (or possibly silver), with a cape, and I believe his suit also had some kind of antennae on its hood. The only scene I can remember was him fighting a bunch of bad guys in some kind of underground complex possibly caverns.

I'm reasonably sure it was filmed during the late sixties as it was in color.  I know this isn't a bunch to go on but I figured I'd take a shot and ask.

Comment: [Prince of Space](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053464/)? - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SuvVjHbubOI

Comment: That was my thought from the title too.

Comment: Wow you guys are good. (it only took you 20 mins.)  The youtube clip was short, but when our hero used his "wand" like device that sparked some memories. It is definitely Prince of Space. I was so sure it was in color lol.  Just shows you what time does to memories :). OK im sure im missing something truly easy here but how do I mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: I don't think its fair to have someone who is omniscient like Valorum on this site... LOL. You so rock.....:)

Comment: @MrInfinity - It helps that it was on MST3K a few years back

Comment: Figures...lol..and the few times I tried variations in google or whatever nothing close ever came up. Here though, on this site. Bam instant answer...:)

Comment: I was feminist with it from http://www.badmovies.org/movies/prinspace/

Comment: @MrInfinity - [It's a gift *and* a curse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0hW0A43n3Y&t=130s)

Comment: "familiar" not "feminist"...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I assumed that's what you meant. Not that there's anything wrong with being a feminist...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Prince of Space](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053464/) from 1959.

Not in colour, but all the other features match. You may be getting confused because the box cover is in colour and/or because the film was featured on Mystery Science Theatre 3000 with interstitial segments (in colour, obviously) parodying the film.